# Subquery used as expression doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery, sql-in

I have theses three tables I just created in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE info_clients(id_client INT(pk),name VARCHAR(20), last_name VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE customer_request(id_request INT(pk),client INT(fk),product INT(fk));
CREATE TABLE info_products(id_producto INT(pk),description VARCHAR(20),price INT);
```

And then I have the next query:

Show the id's of the `clientes` who bought the 10 most expensive items (using a subquery):

```
SELECT id_client FROM info_clients
WHERE id_cliente=(  SELECT client 
                    FROM customer_request 
                    WHERE product=( SELECT id_product 
                                    FROM info_products 
                                    ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 10
                                  )
                 );
```

But I keep getting the message_ subquery used as an expression returned more than one register, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The innermost subquery can return up to 10 records ( `limit 10` clause ), but `product` is a scalar (single) value. You can't compare one value with many values using `=` operator, you need a **scalar subquery** here - the scalar subquery can return at most 1 value, not more. Use `IN` operator instead of =, see this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp.

Comment: Actually both subqueries could return more than 1 rows. And @kordirko, please don't link to that site of junk.

Answer (score 1):

What [@kordirko commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896215/subquery-used-as-an-expression-doesnt-work#comment34942056_22896215).
Plus, JOINs are much faster and better in every respect than (nested) IN expressions.

```
SELECT i.id_client
FROM  (
   SELECT id_product 
   FROM   info_products 
   ORDER  BY price DESC
   LIMIT  10
   ) p
JOIN   customer_request r ON c.product = p.id_product
JOIN   info_clients     i ON i.id_client = c.client;
```

Aslo, typo? `id_cliente` <-> `id_client`
More in the [manual on `SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html).